# Row import failed with error: ("Data truncated for column 'Planetmass_JPT' at row 1", 1265)

Tags: mysql

I have created a table below

```
CREATE TABLE Hospitable_Planets(

Planet_name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
Planetmass_JPT DOUBLE,
Radius_JPT DOUBLE,
Period_days DOUBLE,
Semi_MajorAxis_AU DOUBLE,
Surface_Temp DOUBLE,                /* temparture is in kelivn*/
Discovery_Method VARCHAR(30),
Discovery_Year INT, 
Age_Gyr FLOAT
)
```

However, whenever i try to import the .csv file into this table from manually through the table data import wizard, it gives me this error.
Below are the few lines from the .csv file:

```
PlanetIdentifier,PlanetaryMassJpt,RadiusJpt,PeriodDays,SemiMajorAxisAU,SurfaceTempK,DiscoveryMethod,DiscoveryYear,AgeGyr
KOI-1843.03,0.0014,0.054,0.1768913,0.0048,,transit,2012,
KOI-1843.01,,0.114,4.194525,0.039,,transit,,
KOI-1843.02,,0.071,6.356006,0.052,,transit,,
Kepler-9 b,0.25,0.84,19.22418,0.143,707.2,transit,2010,
Kepler-9 c,0.17,0.82,39.03106,0.229,557.9,transit,2010,
```

Comment: Which is the 'table import wizard'? Are the data separators and options used by the wizard matching your data?

Comment: Isn't there an option to skip the first row?

Comment: The field mames dont match, neither does field count

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed it. I filled out all the empty cells in the excel sheet with 0's and then passed the csv file to the import wizard, it uploaded them to the table. Otherwise the csv file had too many commas together as there was nothing in that column in the excel sheet